# How to pass arguments in command line using dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

the command
`dotnet myapp.dll -- [4, 3, 2]` throws the exception `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`.
I do not know the syntax. How should I pass arguments correctly?
I use powershell.

Comment: Put the arguments in quotes: `"[4, 3, 2]"`

Comment: To shortly explain Sean's comment: arguments are separated by spaces, so `[4, 3, 2]` are three separate arguments: `[4,`, `3,` and `2]`. The quotes override this behavior by saying: everything between both quotes is one argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Arguents does not passed. The programm writes: `System.String[]`

Comment: what writes "System.String[]" what are you actually telling it to display

Comment: `console.write(args);`

Comment: That is the correct output. If `args` is an array of strings, it doesn’t overload `ToString()` so the output will be the type name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join('-', args));
        }
    }
}
```

Call it via Powershell 6:

```
dotnet .\ConsoleApp3.dll "[1,2,3]"
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
```

In the above call, your `Main` method will receive `[1,2,3]` as a single string and you have to parse/split it in your code.

If you want an array reflected in the `string[]` array of `Main` you can use a PowerShell array:

```
dotnet .\ConsoleApp3.dll @(1,2,3)
```

Output:

```
1-2-3
```

Here the PowerShell array `@(1,2,3)` is casted to a `string[]`-array. Therefore each item of the PowerShell array is injected to the `string[]` array.

Behavior is the same on PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: It helps! `dotnet .\myapp.dll @(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Moerwald's answer explains well how to pass array arguments in PowerShell, but:

- The regular arguments of a C# program (`string[] args`) don't need to be sent as an array. Several parameters can be sent, just using spaces. As command line interpreters (PowerShell/CMD/BASH) just consider each of those different parameters, and will send all parameters to the dotnet command, and the dotnet command will send all those parameters to the program.

  Instead of:

  ```
  > dotnet .\ConsoleApp3.dll @(1,2,3)
  1-2-3
  ```

  You can send each argument separated by spaces:

  ```
  > dotnet .\ConsoleApp3.dll 1 2 3
  1-2-3
  ```
- You don't need to do compile the program into a DLL in order to run with dotnet.

  Instead of first compiling the SLN/CSPROJ and then running it:

  ```
  > dotnet build
  > cd bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
  > dotnet .\ConsoleApp3.dll 1 2 3
  1-2-3
  ```

  You can run directly from the SLN/CSPROJ folder via the "run" command:

  ```
  > dotnet run 1 2 3
  1-2-3
  ```