# how to configure .net core Web Application database credentials

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a simple .net core application connecting to mongoDb as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Database connection information is configured in appsettings.json file.

```
  "DataSource": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "Root",
    "CollectionName": "ApiLog"
  },
```

I have a matching class

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;

    public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string CollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I dont want to store db info in a file so how can I configure connection information in a production environment?

I expect something like

```
dotnet app.dll -DataSource.ConnectionString = mongodb://localhost:27017
```

in Program.cs i have;

```
builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("DataSource"))
```

I want to access this configuration whenever i need it via dependency injection

```
public class LogService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<ElekseLog> _collection;
    public LogService(
        IOptions<DatabaseSettings> databaseSettings)
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            databaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

        var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
            databaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

        _collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<ElekseLog>(
            databaseSettings.Value.CollectionName);
    }
}
```

But I couldn't make it work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108617/how-to-pass-arguments-in-command-line-using-dotnet | I think this link can help.

Comment: @AdemCatamak passing arguments is a great idea but can i do it using configuration? like var connectionInfo = builder.Configuration.GetSection("DataSource");

Comment: You want to keep the value in the config for the local and test environment in the json file. If I understand correctly, you want to change this value when the release will be made for the prod environment. You can use EnvironmentVariable values. Or you can search config vault usage by platform that you are using (azure, aws etc). Or if you are using CI pipeline you can modify the json file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
dotnet app.dll --DataSource:ConnectionString=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

And access the value using:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration["DataSource:ConnectionString"];
```

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#command-line-arguments)

Comment: this is working: `dotnet F:\Elekse\c\loc\LogApplication\bin\Debug\net6.0\LogApplication.dll --DataSource.ConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"` but I want to access it like `builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("DataSource"));` where ConnectionString is a field inside  ConnectionSettings class. What is the syntax for this?